# access calling classes atrributes

Tags: python

I have 2 classes defined as such

```
class class1():
    self.stuff = 1
    def blah(self):
        foo = class2()
        foo.start()

class class2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
       #access class1.stuff
```

How would I access class1.stuff from class2

Comment: Your sample is not valid python. `self` is not defined in class bodies. What is it you're trying to accomplish? Is `self` defined in some outer scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
class class1(object):
    stuff = 1
    def blah(self):
        foo = class2()
        foo.start()

class class2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
       print(class1.stuff)
```

There is no special syntax to "access calling classes atrributes". If you want access to a object you must give it a visible name, for example by passing it to `__init__` or by using the class object like this.

Comment: Is there no way to dynamically find which object created the instance of class2 and reference its attributes from within class2 itself? specifically if more than 1 class creates instances of class2 but they all have a specific attribute in common i want to reference?

Comment: @T_Mac: No, not in Python, and I think pretty much all languages avoid magic like that like the plague.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to pass it into the function.

```
class class1():
    self.stuff = 1
    def blah(self):
        foo = class2()
        foo.start(self)

class class2(threading.Thread):
     def run(self, obj):
        obj.stuff;
```

There is no way to access another object's properties without having a reference to the object. The easiest way to obtain a reference to an object of class1 is to ask for it as an argument.

Comment: As @rincewind pointed out above, `self` isn't defined inside of a `class` statement but outside a method, so the first line of `class1`'s definition is invalid.